# I cant get my CRUD to work in visual studio using a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database, hyperlink

Hi im hoping someone would indicate what im doing wrong because it keeps giving an error at my cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-UDQ3PUC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBCtuLogistics;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Address values (@ComplexNumber,@ComplexName,@Street,@Suburb,@City,@Province,@Country,@PostalCode", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplexNumber",(textBox1.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplexName",(textBox6.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", (textBox5.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suburb", (textBox4.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", (textBox3.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", (textBox2.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", (textBox8.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode",(textBox7.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Created!");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, and exception as Text not as screenshots.

Comment: Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed `)` after `@PostalCode`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Address values (@ComplexNumber,@ComplexName,@Street,@Suburb,@City,@Province,@Country,@PostalCode)", con);
```